# Run job every 10 minutes with Clockwork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clockwork

I would like a job to run every 10 minutes in Clockwork, but I want it to run 6 times an hour, at 00, 10, 20, 30, 40, and 50 minutes past.

In the [Clockwork readme](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) it says you can use wildcards for hour and minute values:

> Wildcards for hour and minute are supported:
>
> ```
> every(1.hour, 'reminders.send', :at => '**:30')
> every(10.seconds, 'frequent.job', :at => '9:**')
> ```

However when I tried `at: '**:*0'` it gave me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @benjamin seems to be wildcards characters can be used either or hours or minutes, and seems to be Clockwork doesn't support partial wildcards like `**:*0`

you can pass array to `at` option to achieve your goal [You can set more than one timing](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork#examples)

```
every(10.seconds, 'reminders.send', :at => ['**:00', '**:10', '**:20', '**:30', '**:40', '**:50'])
```